# Game of life returning the number of live cells

Tags: c++, conways-game-of-life

I'm currently working on a game of life project done in c++ and SDL2. I'm storing each individual cell inside a vector<cell*>. The problem is I can't seem to figure out how to address the surrounding cells correctly.

```
    if( it->isAlive() && InputHandler::getInstance()->isKeyDown( SDL_SCANCODE_SPACE ))
    {
      if( ( it + 1 )->isAlive() && (it + 1) != board.back() )
        it->incrementAliveNeighbors();
      if( ( it - 1)->isAlive() && ( it-1) != board.front() )
        it->incrementAliveNeighbors();
      if( ( it + numOfCols)->isAlive() )
        it->incrementAliveNeighbors();
      if( ( it - numOfCols )->isAlive() )
        it->incrementAliveNeighbors();
      if( ( it + (numOfCols + 1) )->isAlive() )
        it->incrementAliveNeighbors();
      if( ( it - (numOfCols - 1) )->isAlive() )
        it->incrementAliveNeighbors();

      it->survive();
      std::cout << "Cell at x: " << it->getXPos() << " y: " << it->getYPos() << " has " << it->getAliveNeightbors() << " alive neighbors! \n";
      it->resetNeighbors();
    }
```

I calculate numOfCols just by dividing the screen width by the cell width. The `survive()` method checks if the cell should survive according to the rules. `resetNeighbors()` just resets the number of neighbors each iteration so they can be checked on the next one. I'm probably doing a ton of things wrong here but this is the best I could figure out. Any help is appreciated

Comment: The main issue I see is that you start `incrementAliveNeighbors` before you are done with one update iteration. As such, you'll modify the board before you're done reading it. Typically, people implement this with **two** arrays of cells. One for current state, one for next state. Then they either copy from one to the other, or swap them.

Comment: Looks like lots of out-of-bound accesses, or unintentionally wrapping around an edge. The first two conditions have attempts to check, but it doesn't help to check *after* using a bad pointer. The rest don't check at all.